# Is the Beta Probability Distribution with $\alpha=\beta=4$ a special kind of Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If you look at a [beta distribution with $\alpha=\beta=4$](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Beta_distribution_pdf.svg) it looks very similar to a [Gaussian distribution](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/74/Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg).  But is it? How can you prove whether a Beta(4,4) distribution is Gaussian or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all they are supported on different sets. The Beta distribution has a pdf which is nonzero only on the interval $(0,1)$, whereas the Normal distribution is nonzero on the entire real line. This means they can't be equal.